# My aside is not going to the right side of the section

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot but *aside* is not going to the right side of the section. I have tried every solution. If there is anything wrong in the code, please correct me. It has been annoying me for few days now. This is my html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = en >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new  1.css">
<title> HOW TO DO :- Difficult things become easy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="1180" /></header>
        <div id="nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href "sdfs">home</a></li>
                <li>categories
                    <ul><li><a href "afsdf">sports</a></li>
                        <li><a href "sdfsd">household</a></li>
                        <li><a href "dfsd">cars</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>contacts</li>
                <li>recipes</li>
                <li>videos</li>
                </ul>

                </nav>
                </div>

    <section id="section">
     <header id= "h">Recipe Of The Day<header>

    </section>  
    <aside>
latest
    </aside>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css is

```
    *{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header,section ,footer, aside, nav ,article ,hgroup{
    display:block;
}
header img{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 21px 28px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 15px 21px 28px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#wrapper{
    max-width:100px;
    margin: 40px 40px;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    }
body {width: 1080px;
    height:100%;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px ;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: CadetBlue;
  display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}
#nav{
    margin-left:90px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom:200px;
    width:1180px;
    background:Gainsboro;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    clear:both;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    }

ul {
        width:50%;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;

  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 21px 28px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}
ul li {
    color:black;
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: LightGrey;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
ul li:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
  background: #555;
  color: black;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 4s color 4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s , ;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: white; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

aside{
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin:20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    padding:30px;   
    background: #E6E6FA;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-box-flex:0;
    opacity:0.6;
    font:bold 25px Century Gothic;

}
section{
    padding:20px;

    width:880px;
    margin-top:40px;
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    }

#h{
    font-family:Impact;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, your aside is not nested within the section, so it wont go to the right of it.
It goes to the left of the body.
you do something like

`<section>
    <asdide>
    </aside>
<section>`

and you use `float: right;` after nesting the aside into the section to make it go the right of the section.
Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bumtkffq/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `<section>...</section><aside>...</aside>` into `<section><aside>...</aside>...</section`. That is, nest the `<aside>` element within the `<section>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I could find some issues in both html and css. please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin377/741sd1xm/) link

Updated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang = en >
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="new  1.css">
           <title> HOW TO DO :- Difficult things become easy</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" "sdfs"="">home</a>
                </li>
                <li>categories
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" "afsdf"="">sports</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" "sdfsd"="">household</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" "dfsd"="">cars</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>contacts</li>
                <li>recipes</li>
                <li>videos</li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>

    <header id="header">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="1180">
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <section id="section">
            <header id="h">Recipe Of The Day
                <header>

                </header>
            </header>
        </section>
        <aside>
            latest
        </aside>

    </div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
    display: block;
}

header img {
    box-shadow: 15px 21px 28px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1080px;
}

.group:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 CadetBlue;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    text-align: center;
    background: CadetBlue;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}

#nav {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
#nav nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 Gainsboro;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1080px;
}

ul {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 21px 28px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}

ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 LightGrey;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    margin-right: -4px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: LightGrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #555;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 4s color 4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s ,;
}

ul li ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #555;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

a:link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

aside {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #E6E6FA;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font: bold 25px Century Gothic;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
}

#section {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 820px;
}

#h {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: the aside in your html is not nested within the section, so he wont get the desired output. You have made the same mistake.

Comment: I created a wrapper div for the aside and section..  Please have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin377/741sd1xm/).